# Animate out React component with hooks (componentWillUnmount)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want my component to fade itself out before the unmounting itself from the DOM tree.
When i use the return value from `useEffect()` I think I am already to late to fade out my rendered element.

Can I delay or pause the `useEffect()` return function to animate out my component (self)?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would be a good idea, but you can always use CSS for this purposes, like animation: fadeOut 500ms

Comment: Have a look at React's [CSSTransition](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition) library. It allows you to wrap your component inside a container and delay the unmount process and animate accordingly.

Comment: I think you should move your animation to parent component that will know when child is not used anymore.